# flask-admin different view for multiple databases

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have two different databases. They are: stock and commodity. Each database has two tables as follows:

```
Stock: User_trade_stock, stock_prices
Commodity: User_trade_commodity, commodity_prices
```

I try to build a web app to handle two databases with flask. When I apply flask-admin to them as follows

```
admin.add_view(UserView(User_trade_stock, db.session))
admin.add_view(UserView(User_trade_commodity, db.session))
```

I gives the following eror:

```
Assertion Error: A name collision occurred between blueprints. Blueprints that are created on the fly need unique name.
```

I tried to add the bind to the db.session as follows

```
admin.add_view(UserView(User_trade_stock, db.session(bind='stock_bind')))
admin.add_view(UserView(User_trade_commodity, db.session='commodity_bind')))
```

I got the following error:

```
scoped session is already present; no new arguments may be specified
```

Any helps would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues.

Flask-Admin uses a view's lower cased class name for the automatically generated Blueprint name. As you are using `UserView` twice you have a Blueprint name collision. To overcome this you can specify an `endpoint` name when you instance a view, for example:

```
admin = Admin(app, template_mode="bootstrap3")
admin.add_view(TestView(StockTest, db.session, category='Stock', name='Test', endpoint='stock-test'))
admin.add_view(TestView(CommodityTest, db.session, category='Commodity', name='Test', endpoint='commodity-test'))
```

and to get the urls of the views you would use the following code:

```
url_for('stock-test.index')
url_for('stock-test.edit')
url_for('commodity-test.index')
url_for('commodity-test.edit')
```

Secondly, if you want to use the [bind feature](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/binds/#referring-to-binds) of Flask-Sqlalchemy you should use the  `__bind_key__` attribute on the table model, for example:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
```

Here is a single file example illustrating both concepts. You will need to run the flask commands `flask create-databases` and `flask populate-databases` before you use the app itself. Note I've used a mixin class, `TestMixin`, to define the model columns.

```
import click
from flask import Flask
from flask.cli import with_appcontext
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from faker import Faker
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, Text

db = SQLAlchemy()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123456790'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
    'stock': 'sqlite:///stock.db',
    'commodity': 'sqlite:///commodity.db'
}

db.init_app(app)


class TestMixin(object):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text(), unique=True, nullable=False)


class StockTest(db.Model, TestMixin):
    __bind_key__ = 'stock'


class CommodityTest(db.Model, TestMixin):
    __bind_key__ = 'commodity'


@click.command('create-databases')
@with_appcontext
def create_databases():
    db.drop_all(bind=['stock', 'commodity'])
    db.create_all(bind=['stock', 'commodity'])


@click.command('populate-databases')
@with_appcontext
def populate_databases():
    _faker = Faker()
    db.session.bulk_insert_mappings(StockTest, [{'name': _faker.name()} for _ in range(100)])
    db.session.bulk_insert_mappings(CommodityTest, [{'name': _faker.name()} for _ in range(100)])
    db.session.commit()


class TestView(ModelView):
    pass


app.cli.add_command(create_databases)
app.cli.add_command(populate_databases)

admin = Admin(app, template_mode="bootstrap3")
admin.add_view(TestView(StockTest, db.session, category='Stock', name='Test', endpoint='stock-test'))
admin.add_view(TestView(CommodityTest, db.session, category='Commodity', name='Test', endpoint='commodity-test'))


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Admin!</a>'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a shot.